# Javascript/jQuery: Split camelcase string and add hyphen rather than space

Tags: javascript, regex, split, camelcasing

I would imagine this is a multiple part situation with regex, but how would you split a camelcase string at the capital letters turning them in to lowercase letters, and then adding a hyphen between each new string?

For example:

> thisString

would become:

> this-string

Comment: In your example, you're not keeping the capital letters, did you mean `this-String`?

Comment: I think @user1048007 wants to keep the captial letter, but then lowercase.

Comment: Wouter is correct. It should end up lowercase.

Answer (score 124):

Try something like:

```
var myStr = 'thisString';

myStr = myStr.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1-$2').toLowerCase();
```

Comment: I think you needed .toLowerCase, but either way I am getting -thisstring

Comment: might want to throw a /g on there: myStr.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1-$2').toLowerCase()

Comment: Awesome! Here are the CoffeeScript Polyfill: String::toDash ?= ->
  @replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1-$2').toLowerCase()

Answer (score 19):

Late to answer, but this solution will work for cases where a single letter is camel cased.

```
'thisIsATest'.replace(/([a-zA-Z])(?=[A-Z])/g, '$1-').toLowerCase();  // this-is-a-test
```

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

```
var token = document.getElementsByTagName('strong')[0].innerHTML,
    replaced = token.replace(/[a-z][A-Z]/g, function(str, offset) {
       return str[0] + '-' + str[1].toLowerCase();
    });

alert(replaced);
```

**Example - http://jsfiddle.net/7DV6A/2/**

Documentation for the string `replace` function:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 1):

```
String.prototype.camelCaseToDashed = function(){
  return this.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1-$2').toLowerCase();
}
// Usage
"SomeVariable".camelCaseToDashed();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why all these solutions are so complex but i simply found this to be enough:

```
function camelCaseToDash(input){ 
     // replace Capital letter with the letter + a dash: '-', then lowercase everything.
     return input.replace(/([A-Z])/g, '-$1').toLowerCase(); 
}    

//or, using a callback function, directly lowercasing.
function camelCaseToDashCallback(input){
     //replace capital letter with lowercase variant + a dash '-'.
     return input.replace(/([A-Z])/g, (x)=> "-"+ x.toLowerCase());
}
```

generally option 1 is faster though: https://jsfiddle.net/4557z/17/